# Proper way to use const, static const or global variables in TI XDAIS algorithm

Tags: c, codec, texas-instruments

I'm trying to make a melpe codec, XDAIS compliant. But i'm pretty confused about proper way to do it.

link to melpe codec : https://github.com/gegel/pairphone/tree/master/melpe
(Thanks to gegel for providing implementation)

I currently did this procedure for G711 codec (which is an extremely simple codec) but now for melpe codec, i don't know what to do with const and static const variables.
for example in classify.c :

```
const int16_t enlpf_coef[EN_FILTER_ORDER] = {   /* Q14 */
    /* the coefs of the filter (NOT h) */
    6764, 4336, -274, -2536, -1491,
    24, -228, -1370, -1502, -480,
    383, 390, 57, -18, 104,
    132, 51
};

const int16_t enhpf_coef[EN_FILTER_ORDER] = {   /* Q14 */
    /* the coefs of the filter (NOT h) */
    7783, -5211, 439, 1707, -483,
    -978, 564, 630, -861, 214,
    205, -86, -82, 43, 26,
    -18, 2
};
```

Reading about XDAIS I found following notes :

- Algorithms **never** allocate memory themselves rather they request memory from application.
- Following the same procedure as said in http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Porting_GPP_code_to_DSP_and_Codec_Engine , first i should compile this codec into a library and then use it in XDAIS wrapper functions (for example process and control methods)
- in FIR filter example provided by TI, there is no const or global variable that should be stored.

Q1 - If i understand correctly algorithms should never use global variables in their implementation. Am i correct ?

Q2 - What about local variables defined in IAlg functions ? What prevent algorithms from defining too much local variables, since in requesting memory from application, algorithms don't mention anything about how much memory they need for their local variables. and where do these variables stored in memory ?

Q3 - If Q1 is correct, how should I treat these global constant variables in XDAIS ? Where exactly should I put them ?

Q4 - What is exactly the difference between requesting scratch memory from application and defining variables we need locally? since scratch memory is uninitialized too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In practice (though not explicitly so specified) block-local variables are stored on the stack (or in registers if possible). As such, they do not count as "allocated" in C parlance. Unless you create local objects of megabyte size, the only real issue is excessively deep recursion overflowing the stack.

Comment: @EOF Thanks for the fast response. Yes you are correct local variables do store on the stack. So what you're saying is algorithms in XDAIS don't specifiy how much stack memory they want in their algAlloc implementation. Am I right ?

Comment: Algorithms *should* indicate their asymptotic (versus input size) memory use (e.g. `O(1)`, `O(n)`, `O(log n)`). If it's bigger than `O(log n)` it probably doesn't belong on the stack in typical imperative languages (functional languages may differ here).